# how to create many to many relationship of student with course in ERD Diagram

Tags: database, erd, entity-relationship

I am making **ERD diagram** of Student and Courses.

(1) I have made "**Have** a" relation of student with Courses. Which means 1 student have many courses.

How can i made a relation of "**a courses have many students**" in **ERD?**

Answer (score 0):

That is a many-to-many relationship in ERD. 
[image]

Comment: [My current ERD] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BVCe1u0m51S52mouiFMq_3ksgREa7p4i)

Comment: Updated. See. https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/resolve-your-many-to-manys-for-accurate-requirements